# Drupal: List Content of Content Type in Node

Tags: url, drupal, filter, content-type

How would I create a node, that will list content by content type(ex. only basic page). It will allow the user to delete or edit the content as well.

I do see that in Node: admin/content I can filter out just basic pages. However I would like a url to where the filter is already apply.

I basically want  the user to click the URL to the filter list of just basic pages.
I am using drupal 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I believe I found my answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8615/what-will-be-the-url-to-show-all-content-type-posts

Comment: I believe view bulk operations might work. Any other suggestions?